# Clustered vs. GMM-based standard errors: which ones to use in asset pricing?

Tags: panel-data, finance, clustered-standard-errors, robust-standard-error, generalized-moments

*This question was posted on [Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/74499) a while ago. While it was received positively there and generated a reasonable amount of views, no answers have been posted. Thus I am reposting it here in the hope of finding a larger pool of experts.*

I am interested in comparing two approaches to obtaining robust standard errors in a panel data model with cross-sectionally correlated errors. Consider estimating an asset pricing model such as the CAPM or a multifactor model using monthly data. [Petersen (2009)](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/22/1/435/1585940) section "Asset pricing application" suggests use of standard errors clustered by time, as this addresses the problem of cross-sectional correlation. (Meanwhile, serial correlation is not much of an issue.) [Petersen (2009)](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/22/1/435/1585940) discusses how time-clustered standard errors fare against alternative approaches such as Fama-MacBeth (works fine) and several other. However, he does not seem to consider GMM estimation that is discussed extensively in Cochrane ["Asset Pricing"](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691121376/asset-pricing) (2005) Part II, e.g. Chapter 11.

On the other hand, Cochrane does mention clustered standard errors and Petersen's paper in his video lecture on the topic; see [here](https://youtu.be/lkFon5Jhw-A?t=294) and again [here](https://youtu.be/lkFon5Jhw-A?t=321). However, he does not compare between clustered standard errors and GMM-based ones either.

So how do clustered standard errors and GMM-based standard errors compare? (If needed, we may consider (1) clustering by time and (2) assuming zero autocorrelation in GMM for concreteness.) Is one a special case of the other? Which ones makes more sense (given that 13 years have passed since Petersen's paper, I guess there should be some consensus on the matter)?

**References**

- Cochrane, J. (2005). [*Asset Pricing: Revised Edition*](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691121376/asset-pricing). Princeton University Press.
- Petersen, Mitchell (2009). ["Estimating Standard Errors in Finance Panel Data Sets: Comparing Approaches"](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/22/1/435/1585940). *Review of Financial Studies 22 (1)*: 435–480.
  (A freely accessible working paper version is [here](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=661481).)

Comment: Related: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/74509, https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/74521.